# Undefined buffer while using svg2img

Tags: node.js, svg

I use svg2img (https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2img) to convert my svg base64 string to png image.

```
base64Img.base64(path + filename, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    let svgString = data;
    svg2img(
        'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(svgString),
        function(error, buffer) {
            fs.writeFileSync('foo2.png', buffer);
    });
});
```

An error appears saying "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined". The very same error appears when I try to convert to image directly from svg file.

How can I fix it? Or maybe you know another way to convert base64 (or svg file itself) to png or jpg format?

Comment: You're trying to do this in the browser?

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm trying to do it in my node server

Comment: did u try console.log('data', data) ? Did your data load correctly?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yup, it shows really long base64 string

Comment: there don't seems to be any thing obvious with the code syntaxes. What happened when you console.log('buffer', buffer) before fs.writeFileSync? The error comes from fs or did it come from svg2img?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it says 'buffer undefined'. The error comes from at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1460:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HDApp\hdapp\server\index.js:133:20
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HDApp\hdapp\node_modules\svg2img\index.js:42:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)